# Angular Routing with wildcards not always working

Tags: angular

Using Angular 4, I have the following in my Routes collection:

```
{
    path:"**",  //wildcard
    component: NotFoundComponent,
}
```

and if I try to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxx I get correctly routed to my NotFoundComponent, however if I try to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxx_(xxx) I do not.  I've tried various permutations of

```
{
    path:"**_(**)",  
    component: NotFoundComponent,
},
```

placed prior to my wildcard path, but they haven't worked either. Thoughts?

Comment: `()` is reserved to auxiliary routes. I assume this is what causes your problems. Can you reproduce with any other characters?

Comment: So far, not yet

Comment: Then it's quite likely what I assumed. You would need to provide your custom https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer that uses different characters to mark aux routes instead of `()`

Comment: I'll look into it - thanks

Comment: I know it's out off topic, but  @Günter Zöchbauer answers/comments are always on the top